# how to divide values of list of dicts by number?

Tags: python

```
a = [{"language": "en-US", "count": 10}, {"language": "en", "count": 3}]
```

I would like to divide the values of the field count by the sum of all counts in this list.

The given result should be:
count/ sum(counts)

```
a = [{"language": "en-US", "count": 0.76}, {"language": "en", "count": 0.23}]
```

I was able to calculate the sum of count values:

```
total_count = sum(d.get('count', 0) for d in a)
```

Comment: Did you want your `"count"` values divided by the sum to be strings again? Does your posted code produce an error?

Comment: How do you say you were able to calculate the sum? Your line gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`...

Comment: Sorry the quote were added when i copied the text. The values are int not string. Im fixing.

Answer (score 1):

you could scroll thought your list and edit the values:

```py
a =[{ "language": "en-US", "count": "10" }, { "language": "en", "count": "3" }]
total_count = sum(int(d.get('count', 0)) for d in a)
for data in a:
  data['count']  = int(data['count']) / total_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a type error: you need to convert these count values to integers.

Try this:

```py
a =[{ "language": "en-US", "count": "10" }, { "language": "en", "count": "3" }]


total = sum(int(item["count"]) for item in a)
# retrieves the value count for each dictionary of a

for item in a :
    item["count"] = str(round(int(item["count"])/total), 2)
    # replace the old count with your actual count (divided by the total)
```

Comment: The general principle of this code is fine except that it does not produce the required output - namely the string representation of a floating point number rounded down to two decimal places

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that more closely resembles the OP's requirements.

As the other answers have stated, you need to convert the numbers from strings to ints. After that, you can use an f-string to format the floats to 2 decimal places.

```py
a = [{"language": "en-US", "count": "10"}, {"language": "en", "count": "3"}]
total_count = sum(int(d.get("count", 0)) for d in a)
for d in a:
    d["count"] = f"{int(d.get('count', 0)) / total_count :.2f}"
```